# Browser stops reading javascript chunk if it is too big without any error message

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser

I have encountered a strange problem in my website.

The main steps are that my web app in Flask processes selected data and sends the results to the user and it is then plotted by D3.js. Some extra tables are also shown etc..

If the resulting data is very big (hundreds of MB), then the page is rendered, the tables are there and no error message is given, however the javascript chunk where the big data is used seems to be ignored by the browser. No global variables or plotting.

If the data is of reasonable size, then everything works, the chunk is executed and variables are there.

I tested this with all modern browsers, no error message. I'm just wondering, why this happens.

All the best, 
L.

Comment: **100+mb** of data `o.O`. My suggestion, perform all processing `avg/percentage` etc on serve and pass processed data. Transferring so much of data is not good

Comment: I agree, but I am really curious why the browser doesn't warn me or give some error, it acts like everything should be like this.

Comment: Honestly, I have never even thought of transferring this amount of data. But as you are saying, there are not errors, its possible, they might have been handled in library as even they would not expect such huge data. Try debugging. Also, 100mb of data will take lot of time to load. Make sure you run d3 processing after entire data is loaded

Comment: It seems that it is not loading the data entirely. In the console I can see that the script is there, the variable with the big data also is shown, but as it is very long, it is not shown entirely, it is not possible to expand the script tag.

Comment: If you log it, dev tools would hang. Only option is to log its length.

Comment: Nothing hangs, at least the feeling is that everything was loaded and is ok. 
In the chunk I have for example: var width=100; and var data={...this big nested json...}; 
even the variable width doesn't exist and it isn't logged nor is the data.length. It just says nothing, not even some error message. The same page with some other (smaller) data works fine, everything is logged etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142143/discussion-between-liis-kolberg-and-rajesh).